# Replace .innerHTML with another .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to show information depending on the value of two tags. 
I got the first one to work. 
When the value of `__ix_data_shared_int_80_` is `0` nothing is showing, when the value is `1` it will show `DV` and when the value is `2` it will show `AV`.

But I can't get the number to work. 
When `__ix_data_shared_int_80_` has the value of `0` I don't want any information, 
when the value is `1` I would like `number` to be equal to the value of `__ix_data_shared_uint_80_` and when the value is `2`  I would like `number` to be equal to the value of "__ix_data_shared_uint_80_` times 2.

```
<span id="type"></span>
<span id="number"></span>
<span data-ix-tag="__ix_data_shared_uint_80_" id="valve" data-ix-refresh="interval"></span>  

<script>
function GetValveTypeString(tag) {
    if (tag.value == 0) {
        document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if (tag.value == 1) {
        document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = "DV";
    }
    else if (tag.value == 2) {
        document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = "AV";
    }
}
iX.createTag('__ix_data_shared_int_80_', GetValveTypeString, 'interval')
</script>

<script>
var valveID = document.getElementById("valve").innerHTML;
function GetValveID(tag) {
    if (tag.value == 0) {
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = "";
    }
    else if (tag.value == 1) {
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = valveID;
    }
    else if (tag.value == 2) {
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = valveID * 2;
    }
}
iX.createTag('__ix_data_shared_int_80_', GetValveID, 'interval')
</script>
```

Comment: Can you produce a working code snippet demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. Share your current results.

Answer (score 0):

It is because {document.getElementById("valve")} is returning empty string and you are trying to manipulate empty string

Comment: Dosn't it get a value on row 3      <span data-ix-tag="__ix_data_shared_uint_80_" id="valve" data-ix-refresh="interval"></span>

Comment: It is set empty.

Comment: How can I transfer the value of "_ix_data_shared_uint_80" into valveID then?

Comment: If the value is an attribute, you can use `document.querySelector('[data-ix-tag="_ix_data_shared_uint_80"]').value` if the value you're referring to is set as an attribute. Else, you can use `document.querySelector('[data-ix-tag="_ix_data_shared_uint_80"]').innerHTML`

Comment: When i try document.querySelector('[data-ix-tag="_ix_data_shared_uint_80"]').value I get the "undefined".

and document.querySelector('[data-ix-tag="_ix_data_shared_uint_80"]').innerHTML just return blank

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to say. Your value attribute is not present and innterHTML is empty/blank.